# How to write properly a groovy unit test with jUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, junit

I am getting started with Groovy and I don't know how to write unit tests over my methods written on a class. For example:

One my methods on **sample.groovy** :

```
class sample {
   
   def length = { list -> list.size() }
   ...

}
```

So, I have one class named **sampleTest.groovy** :

```
class sampleTest extends GroovyTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testLength() {
        def result = length([2, 3, 8, 9, 0, 1, 5, 7])
        assert result == 8
    }

}
```

BTW, when I run this test, an error throws to me:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: sampleTest.length() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[2, 3, 8, 9, 0, 1, 5, 7]]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
...
```

Comment: Have you tried Spock? http://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Nono, i have 2 days learning this awesome language, so i don't know a lot :P
Spock is a better practice to test groovy?

Comment: Error message is fairly self-explanatory. You're calling some unknown method called `length` with a List as an argument...are you intending to write `[2, 3, 8, 9, 0, 1, 5, 7].size()` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`length` is a (non-static) property of the `sample` class. Because it's non-static, you need to evaluate it against a `sample` instance, e.g.

```
class sampleTest extends GroovyTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testLength() {
        def result = new sample().length([2, 3, 8, 9, 0, 1, 5, 7])
        assertEquals 8, result
    }
}
```

Also, you should try to use the assertion methods provided by `GroovyTestCase` such as `assertEquals`, `assertNotNull`, `assertTrue`, rather than the `assert` keyword.

You should also capitalize your class names, e.g. `Sample` and `SampleTest` rather than `sample` and `sampleTest`.

Comment: The [official Groovy homepage](http://www.groovy-lang.org/testing.html) advertises the use of power assertions (`assert` keyword) for testing.